# Api data is not getting fetched when the application is hosted, while It works well in localhost in a react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, netlify, alpha-vantage

I have a react application that fetches data from alpha vantage API. When in localhost, the data is fetched properly and I get the data but when the application is hosted on netlify, there is no data from the API.

Below is the code for fetching the data.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getNews = () => {
      fetch(
        "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=business&apiKey=303be9184122470198a38e255a0edf62"
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => setNews(data.articles))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
    };

    getNews();
  });
```

Comment: Looks like a CORS error. Haev you checked the value of `data`?

Comment: How do I do that ? If possible, can we connect through Google meet? It would help me a lot